# Run a function a random number of times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building an application that generates a view of space with a random number of clickable `stars`. So far I am generating the stars as so:

```
  const makeStars = () => {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7 + 2);

    return (
      <div className="starWrapper">
        <Star
          name={makeid}
          starType={starList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1)]}
        ></Star>
        <h2>Star: {makeid()}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

This is working great, but I want this function to run a random number of times when the pages loads. Here is my attempt so far

```
const makeStars = () => {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7 + 2);
var count = 0 
if (count < num) {
window.setTimeout(function() {
 return(<div className="starWrapper"><Star name={makeid} starType={starList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1)]}></Star><h2>Star: {makeid()}</h2></div>
{() => count + 1})
}, 10); 
}
```

but so far this isn't returning anything and I'm not sure why. I don't know if `setTimeout` is the best tool for the job, and I'm open to any other suggestions you have.

The full page of code is viewable [here](https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/planetviewer/blob/main/src/interstellar-view/interstellar.jsx).

Comment: Just like you are creating random numbers, use Math.random() to run a for loop from 0 to Math.random() + (some offset value). Settimeout is when you want to run something after a specific time gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the function that can be ran a random amount of times.

```
function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function createstars(randnum) {
If (randnum > 0) {
/** Do logic here **/
createstars((randnum - 1))
}
}

createstars(rand(1,10)) /** set min and max to your liking , the rand function is inclusive **/
```

Comment: I am getting a ```RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded``` error. 
My code is like this
 ``` const makeStars = () => {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7 + 2);
    
   if (num > 0) {
        return (
          <div className="starWrapper">
            <Star
              name={makeid}
              starType={starList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1)]}
            ></Star>
            <h2>Star: {makeid()}</h2>
           {makeStars((num - 1))}
          </div>
          
        ); }```

Comment: This is because the variable num is redefined everytime you run the function here it might never stop. The error if because you exceeded the max times you can call the function recursively. So you need to supply the num variable outside the function or the random number will always be overwritten. Another thing is that your makeStars function does not accept any parameters so calling makeStars((num - 1)) does nothing. If you want to access the parameters you can define it like const makeStars = (num) => ...

Comment: How are you assigning the value of randnum with the rand function in your example?

Comment: I called the createstars function with the parameters of rand(1 , 10) , which generates a number between 1 and 10. This number gets passed to the createstars function at randnum and I can access this value from the randnum variable inside the function.

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanations. This is working as intended now.